# Matching () with a Unix/Linux regex

Tags: linux, bash, unix, regex

I have a couple files with the name

```
(a).1
(a).2
...
(a).100
```

Since a lot of processing tools don't really like `(` and `)` in the filename I thought it best to rename them to a different name. I googled for renaming files and found the wonderful tool `rename` where I can feed a regular expression. Okay let's try this:

```
$ rename -v s/\(a\)/b/ \(a\).* 

(a).1 renamed as (b).1
(a).2 renamed as (b).2
(a).3 renamed as (b).3
```

Hmm not what I expected. After a bit of googling I found that `\(` `\)` is a [grouping operator](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-grep-regular-expressions-to-search-for-text-patterns-in-linux#grouping). Which sort of makes sense since I did not escape the `(` `)` in the command.

I solved my renaming problem by using the `.` character that matches all types of values:

```
rename -v s/.b./b/ \(b\).*
```

This solution is not really nice. So how do I match `(` and `)` in Bash/Linux/Unix Regex?

Comment: maybe use single quotes around the round brackets?  by the way, I wasn't able to reproduce any of the results you got http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yhPgtvhG   the rename command you give gives an error when I run it, and does nothing when I space it out a bit. That was in cygwin though that's still bash

Comment: I used a Debian 8.0 with the `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` environment. Maybe cygwin does some weird mangling with the input. I was able to solve this by putting the regex into quotes: `rename -v 's/\(a\)/a/' \(b\).*`.

Comment: It could also be that the regex handling on Cygwin is different than on Linux.

Comment: If I do rename -? it says  `rename [options] expression replacement file..` you've got the expression and the replacement but not the file.    Looks after options (e.g. -v) there are  3 mandatory parameters there, separated by  spaces. But your rename command only has 2 of them.   i'll check my rename version (- uppercase V) `$ rename -V<ENTER>
rename from util-linux 2.24.2`

Comment: I have `rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E *perlexpr*]*|*perlexpr*
    [ *files* ]`. So we have two different versions.

Comment: What version do you have? does your -V give a version?

Comment: yeah it's the version.. debian 8 has the extra switches you have.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need:

```
find -name "(*)*" -type f | rename 's/\(|\)//g'
```

It first finds files in the current directory matching the described name, then renames them by removing the brackets. You can see the matching characters ( and ) are replaced with nothing.

Comment: Ah, I see my problem. I should have used `rename 's/\(a\)/a/'` instead of `rename s/\(a\)/a/`. What is happening here? Why did you introduce the `find`?

Comment: I like find because you can expand the command to do many other things as well as output the list of files for verification before piping to the rename command. There's a switch that will let you test without actioning the changes, but I can't remember what it is at the moment.

Comment: You know that you can use find with an exec? `find . -exec echo {} \;`